# Acceleration of spacecraft with thrust

Tags: rotational-dynamics, acceleration, rigid-body-dynamics, angular-velocity

I am reading the following paper:
http://web.mit.edu/larsb/www/iee_tcst13.pdf (p.3, equation (1))

By(1), we have the following:

$$\ddot{r}=-S(\omega)^2r(t)-2S(\omega)\dot{r}(t)+(g +\frac{T_c(t)}{m(t)})$$
where $T_c(t)$ is the thrust vector.

Obviously,  $g$ comes from gravity and $T/m$ comes from $F=ma$.

I am confused about where does $-S(\omega)^2r(t)-2S(\omega)\dot{r}(t)$ come from?

Comment: Please transcribe the pertinent parts (we have MathJax so this is possible with high fidelity to the original) of the text rather than including images which are unsearchable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am confused about where does $-S(\omega)^2r(t)-2S(\omega)\dot{r}(t)$ come from?

They're using a planet-fixed frame, a frame that rotates with the planet. Therefore the fictitious centrifugal ($-S(\boldsymbol \omega)^2\,\boldsymbol r(t)$) and Coriolis ($-2S(\boldsymbol\omega)\dot{\boldsymbol r}(t)$) accelerations arise.

Note that the $S(\boldsymbol\omega)$ used in that paper is the cross-product matrix.